# What does automount do when no maptype is specified?

Tags: automounting, autofs

I have inherited a server with an entry in `/etc/auto.master` of `/home auto.home`. In the manual on this server (and on another more recent server) it's clear that map-type is optional.

What I can't find documented anywhere is what happens if no map-type is given. Does it use whatever is in nsswitch.conf for "automount"? I can't find anything in `man {nsswitch.conf,automount,autofs,auto.master}` which says this is the defined behaviour.

I can usually understand documentation pretty quickly but auto{fs,mount}'s docs are difficult to follow!

Any explanations greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This obviously doesn't prove this is the case for all versions of Autofs but I've managed to find a guide from Oracle ([Default Autofs Behavior With Name Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0916/6ja8539g7/index.html#rfsrefer-95)) which contains the following image.

[image: How Autofs Uses the Name Service]

This is the only reference I can find that links Autofs to [NSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch). I can only assume this functionality has been duplicated in non-Oracle version of Autofs but left undocumented.

---

I suppose I should have done this first really. In [autofs-5.1.1.tar.gz](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/daemons/autofs/v5/autofs-5.1.0.tar.gz) there is a `lib/nss_parse.y`. And in the CHANGELOG there are a lot of references to NSS, most notably:

```
14/01/2008 autofs-5.0.3
-----------------------
...
- if there's no "automount" entry in nsswitch.conf use "files" source.
```